# Create branches at the same time in two/more repositories in Git

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I am having C# application containing 20 projects in it, all in the same repository in BitBucket.

I am looking to split this into 20 repositories.

I need a standard way for this. Is that correct to split these many projects into many repositories or keep them all in the same repository ?

If we are going to split this to many repositories, how would a developer create a branch in all the repositories in a single click and clone them in all in his machine ?

I am thinking of git commands to create branches.

Is there any option in-built in the Bitbucket ?

Thanks,
R. Venkatesan

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you have 20 projects in 1 SVN repository. Now you want 20 projects in 20 Git repositories, per project inside one Git repository. It's ok.

1 repository is **BigRepo**.

20 projects are: P1, P2, P3, ..., P20.

**Step 1.** You will transform/convert SVN repository to Git. Read manual: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

**Step 2.** Create 20 Git repositories on server, named it R1, R2, R3, ..., R20.

**Step 3.**
Push BigRepo to git repository to R1, delete R2, R3, ... R20. **(1)**

Push BigRepo to git repository to R2, delete R1, R3, ... R20.

Push BigRepo to git repository to R3, delete R1, R2, ... R20.

...

Push BigRepo to git repository to R20, delete R1, R2, ... R19.

**(1)** Tip: For optimization the size of per Git repository, you should un-stage unnecessary folder by:

```
git rm --cached unnecessary_folder
```

before push to Git server. For example, in the context (1),

```
git rm --cached R2 R3 ... R20
```

(replace `...` by real folder name)